# Keyboard shortcut to start new Pidgin IM

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pidgin, launchy

I'm looking for an easy way to use a keyboard shortcut (from anywhere in Windows) to open a new [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) IM window with a contact in my buddy list.

Normally I'd try and use [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) for this (which I use pretty frequently for launching other things), but I've searched and can't find a Pidgin plugin or anything for it that might facilitate this.

So I'm either looking for (in order):

1. A Launchy plugin that will open a new Pidgin IM window (e.g. enter "pidgin contact-name" in the Launchy dialog)
2. A Launchy equivalent (e.g. command-line fu)
3. A non-Launchy global keyboard shortcut

Does anyone know of anything that can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your best bet, which is what I do:

- Use the [Pidgin Hotkeys plugin](http://pidgin-hotkeys.sourceforge.net/) to assign a global hotkey to the buddy list, use that to bring it up.
- Start typing the name of the contact, and pidgin will highlight the name in the buddy list.
- Hit enter, instant message window pops up, start typing your message.

Once you start using it, you'll wonder why you did anything else.

[image]

Comment: I'm close - but strange things happen when I begin typing with the buddy list open. It'll get my first character, but then stop taking character input. It then seems to hang for a bit before responding.

Comment: That's very odd, I've never had a problem with it.

Comment: @The How-To Geek Thanks a lot for the tip with typing the name of the contact in the buddy list (never thought of this). Unfortunately, the link with plugin is now broken (and it seems, that this plugin is not included in the standard package)... But I use calling Pidgin from Launchy - it also opens buddy list.

Comment: @Gareth Also did not experience such a problem: it seems that the reason is in your Pidgin or your system. Anyway, I hope that it's already solved.

Answer (score 1):

1. Execute pidgin from the launchy window (even if it's already running).
2. Type several characters of a contact id.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Begin typing your message.
5. <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close. (assuming you have the preference enabled)

I would encourage use of the history plugin with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are command line tricks you can use if you have the uri handlers installed (this is an option at install so you might want to reinstall)

For jabber (or gtalk)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe" --protocolhandler=xmpp:user@domain.com?message
MSN
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe" --protocolhandler=msnim:chat?contact=user@hotmail.com

There are more as well, you have to look up the syntax for each one 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Unofficial_but_common_URI_schemes

xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0147.html

www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1157/msn-messenger-msnim-hyperlink-command-codes/

Good Luck

Comment: Only allowed to post one link ... thats dumb